# sql max() over (partition by) in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to get the same SQL output for max over partition by, but in pandas.
the goal is to replace the did_renew==No with Yes, but under specific conditions and for a group of the dataframe
This is my datafreame:

```
        date_id               sf_id renewal_date is_up_for_renewal     did_renew  datediff
168  2020-09-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   Yes               Undetermined NaN      
169  2020-08-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0     
170  2020-07-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0     
171  2020-06-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0     
172  2020-05-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0     
173  2020-04-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0     
174  2020-03-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0     
175  2020-02-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0     
176  2020-01-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0     
177  2019-12-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0     
178  2019-11-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0     
179  2019-10-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0     
180  2019-08-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   Yes               No            2.0     
181  2019-07-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0     
182  2019-06-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0     
183  2019-05-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0     
184  2019-04-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0     
185  2019-03-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0     
186  2019-02-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0     
187  2019-01-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0     
188  2018-12-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0     
189  2018-11-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0     
190  2018-10-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0     
191  2018-09-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0     
192  2018-08-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0
```

In SQL I would write: case when dafediff=2 then max('Yes') over (partition by sf_id,renewal_date) end
That would have created a new column with values only for rows 180-192 (see the renewal date is different for rows 168-179, 180-192)
This is how the results should be in column `target`:

```
        date_id               sf_id renewal_date is_up_for_renewal     did_renew  datediff        target
168  2020-09-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   Yes               Undetermined NaN        Undetermined
169  2020-08-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0       Undetermined
170  2020-07-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0       Undetermined
171  2020-06-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0       Undetermined
172  2020-05-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0       Undetermined
173  2020-04-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0       Undetermined
174  2020-03-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0       Undetermined
175  2020-02-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0       Undetermined
176  2020-01-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0       Undetermined
177  2019-12-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0       Undetermined
178  2019-11-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0       Undetermined
179  2019-10-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2020-09-30   No                Undetermined  1.0       Undetermined
180  2019-08-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   Yes               No            2.0       Yes         
181  2019-07-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0       Yes         
182  2019-06-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0       Yes         
183  2019-05-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0       Yes         
184  2019-04-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0       Yes         
185  2019-03-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0       Yes         
186  2019-02-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0       Yes         
187  2019-01-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0       Yes         
188  2018-12-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0       Yes         
189  2018-11-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0       Yes         
190  2018-10-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0       Yes         
191  2018-09-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0       Yes         
192  2018-08-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA  2019-08-31   No                No            1.0       Yes
```

The full dataframe would include many groups of sf_id's so I know I need to use the groupby method for  `[sf_id,renewal_date]` but not sure how to accomplish this
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't understand how it should be the expected output, but if it has a function very similar to SQL over in pandas it is the [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html)

Comment: I edited my question to show the target column if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

```
df['target'] = (df.assign(target=df['datediff']==2))\
                  .groupby(['sf_id', 'renewal_date'])['target']\
                  .transform('max').map({True:'Yes',False:'Undetermined'})
```

Output:

```
        date_id               sf_id renewal_date is_up_for_renewal     did_renew  datediff        target
168  2020-09-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2020-09-30               Yes  Undetermined       NaN  Undetermined
169  2020-08-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2020-09-30                No  Undetermined       1.0  Undetermined
170  2020-07-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2020-09-30                No  Undetermined       1.0  Undetermined
171  2020-06-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2020-09-30                No  Undetermined       1.0  Undetermined
172  2020-05-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2020-09-30                No  Undetermined       1.0  Undetermined
173  2020-04-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2020-09-30                No  Undetermined       1.0  Undetermined
174  2020-03-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2020-09-30                No  Undetermined       1.0  Undetermined
175  2020-02-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2020-09-30                No  Undetermined       1.0  Undetermined
176  2020-01-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2020-09-30                No  Undetermined       1.0  Undetermined
177  2019-12-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2020-09-30                No  Undetermined       1.0  Undetermined
178  2019-11-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2020-09-30                No  Undetermined       1.0  Undetermined
179  2019-10-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2020-09-30                No  Undetermined       1.0  Undetermined
180  2019-08-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2019-08-31               Yes            No       2.0           Yes
181  2019-07-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2019-08-31                No            No       1.0           Yes
182  2019-06-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2019-08-31                No            No       1.0           Yes
183  2019-05-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2019-08-31                No            No       1.0           Yes
184  2019-04-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2019-08-31                No            No       1.0           Yes
185  2019-03-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2019-08-31                No            No       1.0           Yes
186  2019-02-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2019-08-31                No            No       1.0           Yes
187  2019-01-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2019-08-31                No            No       1.0           Yes
188  2018-12-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2019-08-31                No            No       1.0           Yes
189  2018-11-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2019-08-31                No            No       1.0           Yes
190  2018-10-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2019-08-31                No            No       1.0           Yes
191  2018-09-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2019-08-31                No            No       1.0           Yes
192  2018-08-01  0010O00001n1s1rQAA   2019-08-31                No            No       1.0           Yes
```

Details, much like your *case when* I am creating/`assign` a temporary column 'target' that is True when datediff equals to 2.  Then, I am going to `groupby` this column just like your *partition by* on 'sf_id' and 'renewal_date'.  Next we use `transform` to get that max 'target' for that group hence create True for all records in a group where any record has datediff equal to 2.  Lastly, we use `map` to change the True to Yes and False to Undetermined.

Comment: @nimi1234 You're welcome.  Happy coding.  Be safe and stay healthy.